# Ajax Calender Control Toolkit Style sheet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

[image]

```
                <style>
                .ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_invalid .ajax__calendar_day
                 {
                  background-color:gray;
                  color:White;
                  text-decoration:none;
                  cursor:default;
                  }
```

i apply the Style, it'snot working,, i want to change the style of the disabled date,,,

So please help me if anybody have some hints.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the days which are not in the current month, that appear as a different style, then you can change the style using the class;

```
.ajax__calendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_day{
    background-color: #fff; border-color: #fff; color: #646464;
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, then here is a complete list of the styles:

[Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar Styles](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/ACTCodeSamples/WebResource.axd?d=RVYtgrUS9cWE07tuJoB1a2eK5rdm4QdvqH76lAsXbGDzm-srFYap5c02FaOGgIb4OMZzeXRKKAnzMHyv1mB3CRqD_RsNXCgC1J_wL7K2-UEsUTkdhgbI_XabkflOuEU1j9iBj5puFjwiFB805a03qA2&t=634085729415898654)